# How to install programs like "wine" or "dolphin"

Tags: wine

I am very new to ubuntu. I have been tring to load "Wine" and "Dolphin" on my system. Every thing I have tride and all the instruction I have followed have been useless. Is there a straight forward non-geek way for me to install these programs?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Another option is to use `PlayOnLinux`, which can be installed via software-center. It will guide you step by step through the process of installing your windows software of choice, starting with wine, since this is essential. http://www.playonlinux.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to:

1. Open the Ubuntu Software Center
2. In the search box in the software center type in the programs you are looking for(in this case you'll be typing in "dolphin" to find the Dolphin file manager(I'm assuming that's the "dolphin" you're looking for), and type in "Wine" in the search box to find wine.
3. You'll need to know your password(it should be the same as your login password by default) in order to install software from the software.
4. Once you have the software installed, you'll be ready to start using the applications.

That's about all you need to do.

You could also use Synaptic Package manager to do roughly the same, but it's easier for someone like you for now to just use the Software Center since it's easier and more straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

You can find both them in Ubuntu Software Center.

For example [dolphin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dolphin/)

Or else to install them both from the termnial, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine dolphin
```